# Cascading Dropdown in .NET Core Razor Pages(Without MVC/Controller)

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, cascadingdropdown

Someone please give an example of cascading dropdown list in Razor Pages without MVC.
I am using Entity Framework,I have a Model and in Pages a .cshtml page and a corresponding .cshtml.cs page, there is no separate view and controller.

I have searched a lot on the web for this but all of the examples involved are showing MVC examples.

A list of countries has to be fetched from the database and based on the country the below State dropdown should populate from the db.

I am stuck with this since long time.

Comment: You can apply the same code from MVC that you found to razor pages. if you look into the Microsoft docs there is a movie app that creates a search box and you can use the same technique to solve your problem.

Comment: Hi Causita, I need a cascading dropdown(loading one dropdown depending on other dropdown selected value) but couldn't find a suitable solution, tried with the mvc solution which didn't work.

Comment: Post the code and what you have tried and we can help you.